# How to create indexes in mongoDB using code?

Tags: mongodb, database-indexes

I searched this in the Internet and found db.collectionName.createIndex() method. But in this way the index must be set in terminal if local database or using some UI in Mongo Atlas.But when we share our code index won't be created at their end for their table.Is there any way to create an index using code like we do in sql while declaring a primary key.

Comment: Do you mean `db.getCollection("collectionName").createIndex()`?

Comment: In this way if posts is a collection,db.posts.createIndex({ my_id1: 1 }, {unique: true});

Comment: Yes, `db.posts.createIndex({ my_id1: 1 }, {unique: true});` or `db.getCollection("posts").createIndex({ my_id1: 1 }, {unique: true});` or `db.getSiblingDB("myDB").posts.createIndex({ my_id1: 1 }, {unique: true});` or `db.getSiblingDB("myDB").getCollection("posts").createIndex({ my_id1: 1 }, {unique: true});`

Comment: Can you please help me to know how can we do this in code using express